# Linux mint 18.1 does not boot. Shows error log always ending with end trace

Tags: linux-mint, login, logs

After this login prompt: [image]
It should go to the user login menu, but instead it shows this log: [image]
Always ending with an `end trace` line.

Comment: Seems a Kernel error. Probably module or hardware related. Try to boot up with verbose mode on.

Comment: How can I boot into verbose mode? I have no terminal and no tty

Comment: Is this a fresh install?

Comment: No. But the computer boots and works with a linux mint livre cd